# Why is there no current standard synthesizable subset of VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I was a bit nervous about the synthsizability of certain VHDL features, so I thought it might be a good idea to see what is written in the standard (IEEE 1076.6 "IEEE Standard for VHDL Register Transfer Level (RTL) Synthesis").
To my astonishment, I found that there is no current standard: the 1999 version has been superseded by the 2004 version; the 2004 version has the status "withdrawn":
https://standards.ieee.org/standard/1076_6-2004.html

I find it hard to believe that there is no need for a standard subset, so 
I hope someone can explain why the appears to be no current standard.

Comment: Probably because It is still changing. e.g. Vivado 2017 had no synthesis for division, but I have been told Vivado 2018 has.

Comment: The problem is - you get different vendors with different technologies. Surely mandating synthesis requirements may limit their technological capabilities. Synth tools are forever changing and what will synthesise and what wont is always changing. Forcing rules about it would probably force it to the lowest common denominator.

Comment: You'll find FPGA and other synthesis tool vendors in principle support the administratively [withdrawn](https://standards.ieee.org/about/policies/opman/sect9.html) standard. While there are vendors who don't meet all the requirements of the withdrawn standard there are also those who exceed it. This can serve vendor lock-in along with unique HLS efforts. What drives standardization when you remove [interoperability and compatibility](https://standards.ieee.org/develop/overview.html)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Agreeing on a synthesis standard would force the big players to implement all these features. Currently, the big vendors don't have any interest in HDL like VHDL, Verilog, ... Synthesizing division is not new. Xilinx ISE could also synthesize divisions. But anyhow, effective division needs a clock and that cannot be inferred from a one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First DASC made them joint standards with IEC.   When this happened, the numbers changed - which made them hard to find.

Some time later, both the VHDL and Verilog standards were retired by DASC (Design Automation Standards Comittee) because no one stepped forward to maintain them.   Since I do not generally attend DASC meetings, I missed that this happened.

I worked on the VHDL RTL standard.   It lacks reward when you put forward coding styles and attributes and vendors such as Xilinx and Altera do not implement them.

It can be revived.  It is worth reviving if you can get the tool vendors (Xilinx, Altera, Synopsys, Mentor, and Cadence)   participating and implementing the standard.

However, without them participating and committing to implement new features, then the effort by a user led committee would not be worth the time.

If you think of just the statemachine and ROM/RAM attributes, we really need some consistency out of industry - the current state is embarrassing.

Comment: Thanks for all the work. , I would really like to see some of the new features of the 2017 standard become synthesizable in our time. It is indeed

Comment: Sorry for the garbled message, I cannot make up my mind in 5 mins while editing. The new 2017 standards do solve exactly the stuff that has been bugging me, and some of these changes would make VHDL a more Modern (as in "eat my dust C++") Synthesis language, if implemented.